# Number of order permutations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Can someone explain how a set {1,2,3,.....,n} has n!/6 many permutations where 1 is to the left of 2 and 3, and 2 is to the left of 3. This works for all the n I tested but I can't make sense of why. Thanks for any clarification

Answer (score 3):

The different orders of $\{1,2,3\}$ are uniformly distributed among the $n!$ different permutations.

Since there are $3!$ different such orders, each one of them appears in $\frac{1}{3!}$ of all permutations:

- In $\frac{1}{3!}$ of all permutations, the order is $123$
- In $\frac{1}{3!}$ of all permutations, the order is $132$
- In $\frac{1}{3!}$ of all permutations, the order is $213$
- In $\frac{1}{3!}$ of all permutations, the order is $231$
- In $\frac{1}{3!}$ of all permutations, the order is $312$
- In $\frac{1}{3!}$ of all permutations, the order is $321$

Hence there are $\dfrac{n!}{3!}$ permutations in which the order is $123$.

Answer (score 2):

You can count those permutations by taking any permutation of {1,...,n} and replacing 1,2,3 with the order specified by your constraints. There are 3! permutations which will be mapped to the same permutation (depending on the order 1,2,3 appear) so you're overcounting by a factor of 3! so you have n! /3!.